# Where do I put "options" page on manifest v2 (browser extension)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am a browser extension developer, but I don't know where to put the "options" on the manifest (v2), could you give me an example?

Comment: have you tried: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/options/ ?

Comment: But that id for manifest v3

Comment: what do you mean? it says on the page "the page you're viewing describes extensions using Manifest V2", the example you are looking for is here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/options/#full_page

Comment: The reason why I am asking this question is that google says "
Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 27, column: 3, Syntax error", it meant that   "options_page": "options.html", is misspelled

Comment: I see; I suspect on line 26 of this manifest, it is missing a comma at the end. If this does not solve it, please share the manifest so we can help debug.

Comment: It did not solved the problem, when I put the comma, it said "
Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 25, column: 1, Trailing comma not allowed."

Comment: here is my code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DpHBSzbDUcUyIgyXWQJYBpnVRktX3oWO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: remove the trailing comma after "options.html" then it is valid.